# meteor crashes when trying to access .docx files

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an app that uploads user content using meteor-upload server.  Everything works great when the content is a pdf or an image, but the app crashes if the user uploads a .docx or .pptx or other office xml document:

`TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I've checked that the request is sending the correct headers, and it seems to be correct.  When I run this on my server with nginx, even with the MIME type defined, it crashes the app.  When I run it locally, it does one of two things: it either gives me a 503 error or it gives me a "files.json" file that, if I change the extension to the intended file extension, i.e. to files.docx, it opens the correct file.

Any ideas about how to remedy this problem?

Comment: Could it be size related? Does it work for very small docx files?

Comment: good thought, but no, it doesn't work for any small docx files.  and in contrast, it works fine for large pdf files.

Comment: That TypeError ought to point to a line of code, it might help people to help you if you included more context and some code.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I would have posted the line of code if it was a meaningful error allocation. but it points to several files in the meteor-upload package's node module dependencies, middleware/static.js and send.js.  I'll try and dig through those and see if I can figure out what's going on.  You might be onto something, I can see that static.js sends headers for static files... just coming from a LAMP background I'm maybe a little bit privileged in assuming static files are easy to serve to the client, regardless of mime type.

Comment: could you try a doc instead of docx? it is far fetched, but I remember ages ago getting into trouble on tomcat with 4 character extensions.

Comment: just tried, sadly, no dice :-\